# How to draw real time linechart mpandroid from reading data from file and plotting continuously?

Tags: android, real-time, runnable, linechart, mpandroidchart

i am newbie in android,i have class names LedControl,i have to display realtime linechart in mpandroid. I have tried lot but all vain.but no linechart is drawing.Please Help with full code.

i have class LedControl where i have code for hc-05 Bluetooth connection. After that in my inner class ConnectBt extended asyntask.I am taking data from hc-05 continuously and writing data in file hco5.csv.The data is in this format date,time,temperature,gasval,x,y,z(ex:"11/03/2021,09:12:30,45,56,0.67,0.45,0.89")and reading same file,now i have to read the file and plot linechart continously until i stop the process from android studio.I have addEntry method,that i am calling addEntry method from thread

```
  Class LedControl
  {
       fileOutputStream=openFileOutput("hco5.csv",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //called Connectb innner class that extended Asyntask``
       `new LedControl.ConnectBT().execute();`
    `   //calling addEntry from main class to plot linechart`

         new Thread(new Runnable() 
         {

            @Override`
            public void run() 
            {

            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {

            @Override

            public void run() 
            {
             addEntry();
            }
            });
           
           try 
           {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
           }
           catch (InterruptedException e)
           {
           }
           }
           }
         }).start();



      //inner class where i m write data from Bluetooth in file n reading same 

         public class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
         {
          private Boolean ConnectSuccess = true;
          @Override
          protected  void onPreExecute ()
          {
          //progress = ProgressDialog.show(LedControl.this, "Connecting...", "Please Wait!!!");
          }

      @Override
         protected Void doInBackground (Void... devices)
         {
          try 
          {
            if ( btSocket==null || !isBtConnected ) {
                myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                BluetoothDevice dispositivo = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);
                btSocket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                btSocket.connect();
          }
          }
          catch (IOException e) 
          {
               ConnectSuccess = false;
          }

          return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute (Void result)
         {
          super.onPostExecute(result);

          if (!ConnectSuccess)
          {
             msg("Connection Failed. Is it a SPP Bluetooth? Try again.");
             finish();
          } else
          {
            msg("Connected");
            isBtConnected = true;

            if ( btSocket != null ) 
            {
            try
            {
             String line = null;
             LineData data = lineChart.getData();
             //btSocket.getOutputStream().write(number.toString().getBytes());
             inputStream=btSocket.getInputStream();

             while (true)
             {
               
             try
             {
                 bytesCount = inputStream.read(buffer);
                 String message = new String(buffer, 0, bytesCount);
                 //Thread.sleep(1000);
                  fileOutputStream.write(message.getBytes());
                  Log.d("TAGh", "Received message: " + message);
                  fileInputStream = openFileInput("hc05xyz.csv");
                  BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));

                  while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                  {
                   // Log.e("file data", line);
                   parse = line.split(",");

                   for (int i = 0; i < parse.length; i++)
                   {
                    // Log.d("TAGh", "data " + parse[i]);
                     date.add(parse[i]);
                     String a=parse[++i];
                     res =a.split(":");
                     //maketime(res);
                     bul=parse[++i];
                     //makegas(bul);
                     //temp.add(parse[++i]);
                     // bul=parse[++i];
                     // makegas(bul);
                     gas.add(parse[++i]);
                     Xyz xyz1 = new Xyz();
                     xyz1.setX(parse[++i]);
                     xyz1.setY(parse[++i]);
                     xyz1.setZ(parse[++i]);
                     xyzs.add(xyz1);                           

                     }

                     }

                     } 
                      catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                     {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    }

                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                   {
                    msg("Error");
                   }
                   datadate.setText(date.get(0));
                   }
                  }
                  }
                  }


                private void addEntry() 
                {
                 LineData data = lineChart.getData();

               if (data != null)
               {

                ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

                if (set == null) {
                set = createSet();
                data.addDataSet(set);
               }
              //sample from google
              data.addEntry(new Entry((float) ((Math.random() * 20) + 2f), set.getEntryCount()), 0);
             // let the chart know it's data has changed
              data.notifyDataChanged();
             lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

             // limit the number of visible entries
             lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(15);

             // move to the latest entry
             lineChart.moveViewToX(data.getEntryCount());
            }
`           } 
            }
```

Comment: Nobody can run the code you posted since it depends on your Bluetooth setup - come up with a minimum reproducible example that someone else could run and use that to ask. I posted an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76116122/9473786) of a working realtime chart.